# Connecting Touch Up Inside event to File's Owner

Tags: ios5

I’m working through the Multiview Applications chapter of Apress’s Beginning iOS5 development and ran into an issue making a connection from a button on one of the views to File Owner. The general premise of the program is to use a root controller, BIDSwitchViewController to switch between two content views BIDBlueViewController and BIDYellowViewController. Each of the content views has a single button connecting the Touch Up Inside event to the File’s Owner. I had no problem making the connection in BIDBlueViewController, but when I attempt to make this connection in the BIDYellowViewController I’m unable to make a connection between the Touch Up Inside event and the File’s Owner icon.

The instructions in the book state

> Drag a Round Rect Button from the library over to the view, using the
>   guidelines to center the button in the view, both vertically and
>   horizontally. Double-click the button, and change its title to Press
>   Me. Next, with the button still selected, switch to the connections
>   inspector drag from the Touch Up Inside event to the
>   File's Owner icon, and connect to the blueButtonPressed action method

I’m able to do this without any issues, however when I try complete this instruction for the Yellow View

> Drag a Round Rect Button from the library over to the view, using the
>   guidelines to center the button in the view, both vertically and
>   horizontally. Double-click the button, and change its title to Press
>   Me. Next, with the button still selected, switch to the connections
>   inspector drag from the Touch Up Inside event to the
>   File's Owner icon, and connect to the yellowButtonPressed action method

The File Owner icon will not let me make the connection, as I drag from the Touch Up Inside event to the File Owner icon File Owner never highlights and I cannot make the connection.

Here is my code

The root controller interface

```
//
//  BIDSwitchViewController.h
//  ViewSwitcher
//
//  

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BIDYellowViewController;
@class BIDBlueViewController;

@interface BIDSwitchViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDYellowViewController *yellowViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDBlueViewController *blueViewController;

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender;

@end
```

The root controller implementation

```
//
//  BIDSwitchViewController.m
//  ViewSwitcher
//

#import "BIDSwitchViewController.h"
#import "BIDYellowViewController.h"
#import "BIDBlueViewController.h"

@implementation BIDSwitchViewController
@synthesize yellowViewController;
@synthesize blueViewController;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.blueViewController = [[BIDBlueViewController alloc]
                               initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.blueViewController.view atIndex:0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender{
    if (self.yellowViewController.view.superview == nil){
        if (self.yellowViewController == nil) {
        self.yellowViewController = 
    [[BIDYellowViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"YellowView" 
                                              bundle:nil];
    }
    [blueViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];
} else {
    if (self.blueViewController == nil){
        self.blueViewController = [[BIDBlueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueView" 
                                                                          bundle:nil];
    }
    [yellowViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.blueViewController.view atIndex: 0];
    }
}



- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Release the view if it doesn't have a super view
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc, that aren't in use
    if (self.blueViewController.view.superview == nil){
        self.blueViewController = nil;
    } else {
        self.yellowViewController = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

The blue content view controller interface

```
//
//  BIDSwitchViewController.h
//  ViewSwitcher
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BIDYellowViewController;
@class BIDBlueViewController;

@interface BIDSwitchViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDYellowViewController *yellowViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BIDBlueViewController *blueViewController;

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender;

@end
```

The blue content view controller implementation

```
//
//  BIDBlueViewController.m
//  ViewSwitcher
//
//  

#import "BIDBlueViewController.h"

@interface BIDBlueViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDBlueViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

The yellow content view controller interface

```
//
//  BIDYellowViewController.h
//  ViewSwitcher
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDYellowViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)yellowButtonPressed;

@end
```

The yellow content view controller implementation

```
//
//  BIDYellowViewController.m
//  ViewSwitcher
//
//  

#import "BIDYellowViewController.h"

@interface BIDYellowViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDYellowViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: If you select the File's Owner that doesn't work for you and examine it in the Identity Inspector view, what class is the object set to?

Comment: Thanks Phillip. After posting my question I hunted around on Stack Overflow for File's Owner and cane to the same conclusion. I had the yellowView set to NSObject rather than BIDyellowViewController